# Arduino and iPhone via WiFi

Tags: arduino, iphone

First of all, I can control Arduino from iPhone by using Processing and TouchOSC app.

But my task is to achieve a control wirelessly "without using a PC" in between. I need to control Arduino directly by iPhone via "wifi". I should only use an Arduino, a shield, an iPhone and the wifi network. This is the task i am given.

I am really confused which way to use and which shield to buy.

I would be so glad to have your opinions.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [WiFly Shield](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9954) is basically a pcb with a [Roving Networks](http://www.g2microsystems.com/) WiFi module on it. You can configure it to set up an Access Point and connect your iPhone to the same AP.

I haven't used the WiFly Shield but I have used the Roving Networks WiFi modules and they are very flexible. They got a complete WiFi stack onboard and are pretty straightforward to use.

Comment: many thanks for the lead! i am a bit novice. i was using processing running on pc. but now i need a sketch/code to make wifly accept osc. i just need a simple sketch to upload to arduino. i need to turn on or off a led from iphone. any ideas about the code and configuration part? not so much clear explanation on net.